# ContentSize when Zooming in scrollViewDidZoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am having trouble with ContentSize in my scroll view.  I have a scrollview which contains an ImageView which is the same size as the ScrollView.

I have pinching and scrolling the image working perfectly.

The only thing left to do is something with the ContentSize.  I have tried many things, but it seems whenever I pinch to Zoom the image and then I scroll around the image, I have about 5 x as much white space around the image than is necessary to fit the image.

I don't completely understand where ContentSize fits in and what it should be set to.  I assume I need to change this during scrollViewDidZoom?

I don't know how it works.  I don't know when it should be set and what value it should be set to.  Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the `contentSize` when you create the scroll view, and you need to assign it the size of the UIImage you are trying to display inside it. After that, you needn't do anything else.

Also, remember to have the delegate method `viewForZooming~` to return your `UIImageView`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, everything is like this.  I still see huge white space at the top and bottom, but not on the left and right when panning.  This is with a landscape image.  Could it be that when I am zooming, the white space at the top and bottom is getting proportionally bigger that's why it keeps growing as I zoom?  I don't see why, but it's a theory.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what's happening.  When I change contentMode to ScallToFill when I pinch and pan it fills the area as needed.  The height is stretched to fill and that is where the extra white space is when I am using AspectFit.  I need a way to solve this as when I am zoomed in, there are pages of white space at the top and bottom.

Comment: Could you explain this a little better?  Why does ContentSize need to be the same size as the Image?  Setting this has no effect, so if you tell me the reason it needs to be set I can determine a workaround.